# In Django, how can I have a dropdown that loads data and a submit button that commits data on the same html page?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working on my first Django site.  I setup an html page that accepts user inputs, runs calculations, saves to the database, and displays output values into a form when the user hits a submit button.  Now I would like to add functionality for a dropdown to call up one of those submissions from the database if a user selects a item from the dropdown.  So, I created a second form on the same html page for the drop down and successfully populated the dropdown list, however, can't figure out how to load data to the original form when the dropdown is selected.  I think this can be accomplished with form attributes, but I am not sure.

Example:

if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
     This posts the users inputs to the db and displays the calculation

elif request.method == 'GET' and 'dropdown' in request.POST:
     Here lies the problem.  When I select an item in the dropdown nothing
     happens, or I get an error on the page load.  I have tried lots of 
     different approaches the above is the latest.

else:
     A bunch of variables = None

Can anyone provide some coaching or an example?